# How are MacVim's settings related to .swp files unique from other versions of Vim and how can I override them?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have been using Vim casually for around 3 years (mostly for git commit messages) and recently started using it exclusively for text editing and coding while I work my way through a series of intermediate tutorials and resources. Up until a few weeks ago, I primarily used either Vim, NeoVim or iVim (on iOS).

Recently I installed MacVim and started using it exclusively when I'm working in iTerm on a Mac. I have noticed some differences in the way `.swp` files are created and managed. In the other versions of Vim that I have used, `.swp` files are only created when I have a file open in more than one instance of Vim at the same time. It seems that MacVim creates `.swp` files for every open file (I'm guessing for backup/restore purposes). MacVim also seems to put .swp files into the working directory. I don't recall other versions of Vim doing this but it recently led me to add `*.swp` to my global Git ignore settings.

Before drafting this question I did a quick search for: `vim macvim swp files` and found one result that gave me a few ideas on how to work around one of the issues that I've noticed:

[Vim Swap Files Not Deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901886/vim-swap-files-not-deleting)

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255877/vim-swp-files-interfere-with-repository-vimdiff) that gives the impression that the following settings are involved:

```
backup / nobackup
writebackup / nowritebackup
swapfile /noswapfile
```

But this doesn't really answer my question, which is "What is different?". I am editing my `.vimrc` regularly and would like to add in the appropriate settings to get the same behavior in MacVim by default (while also [understanding what I am adding](https://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html)). What is unique about the way MacVim is setup related to swap files? Is there a specific combination of the three settings mentioned above or are more settings involved?  How can I set up the same default behavior I have noticed in Vim, NeoVim, and iVim?

I have read the [MacVim FAQ](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/wiki/FAQ) and [Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting) but didn't find any relevant information.

Comment: 1. MacVim is just Vim; it does everything Vim does, in the exact same way. 2. The behaviour you describe is the expected behaviour. 3. This is not a programming question so you should use [a more appropriate support channel](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_mac).

Comment: Yes, I understand that MacVim is "just Vim" as you say. Vim is highly customizable but most versions seem to conform with the same defaults. The behavior (in my opinion) is not expected because no other versions of Vim behave the same way with regards to swap files. I'm not suggesting that MacVim is broken, just that it is different when it comes to these settings and I would like to understand why. When I searched for an answer, I found the most useful information here in the posts that I linked above so this seemed like a good place to ask my question.

Comment: Two of the "other versions of Vim" you mention are not "other versions of Vim"; they are not Vim at all so they shouldn't form the basis for your understanding of how Vim works.

Answer (score 0):

The default location for a swap file is determined by `:help 'directory'`. Given the default value, Vim will try the directory of the file for which the swap file is created first, appending the `.swp` extension. If it can't create the swap file there, it will try the next location in `'directory'`:

The file:

```
_posts/2018-07-31-npm-201.markdown
```

The swap-file:

```
_posts/2018-07-31-npm-201.markdown.swp
```

If a swap file already exists for a file you are trying to edit and you decide to edit it anyway, another swap file is created at the same location, with a different extension: `.swo`, `.swn`, etc.

What I described above is the normal, expected, behaviour. And that's how MacVim works.

> In the other versions of Vim that I have used, `.swp` files are only created when I have a file open in more than one instance of Vim at the same time.

Those "versions of Vim" are either:

- broken,
- weirdly configured,
- not Vim.

> It seems that MacVim creates `.swp` files for every open file (I'm guessing for backup/restore purposes).

You guessed right, and yes, that's the expected behaviour in every Vim.

> MacVim also seems to put `.swp` files into the working directory.

If the file is in the working directory it's normal. If it's not, the working directory may be part of `'directory'`. If it's not, you have found a bug.

> I don't recall other versions of Vim doing this but it recently led me to add `*.swp` to my global Git ignore settings.

It's very common to have a Vim section in there.